# integrate Argo rollouts dashboard into react application

Tags: reactjs, node.js, argo, argo-rollouts

I have an existing react application where I want to integrate the argo rollouts dashboard(https://argoproj.github.io/argo-rollouts/dashboard).
The library URL: https://github.com/argoproj/argo-rollouts
Dashboard URL: https://argoproj.github.io/argo-rollouts/dashboard

```
Node: 14
Npm: 6
React: 17
```

I can include the rollouts library in my project but after that, I can not see the document for the react application. Event I can not find any documentation related to argo rollouts documentations with react.

Thanks in advance